# .NET Multi-Target with .NET Standard and Portable Library MSBuild 15

Tags: c#, f#, visual-studio-2017, portable-class-library, msbuild-15

Porting to .NET standard version, you may be source identical to a portable library, but the platforms supported may not.

For example `.NET standard 1.6` might be the lowest version that has your api's available from portable `Profile47`. `Profile47` supports *.net 4.5 or later*, nut `.NET Standard 1.6` only supports *4.6.1 and later*!

With the new multi-targeting with the new **msbuild 15** csproj/fsproj *(also VS2017)* is it possible to compile for both a **Portable Library** and **.Net Standard** at the same time to make the transition easier?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The prior answer is accurate but it's not actually enough. You need to reference the Portable language targets to get the correct behavior. There also may be other SDK references and you'll probably want implicitly defined `ifdefs` like `PROFILE328`.

I wrote a NuGet package you can add to your project that "does the right thing" here:

https://github.com/onovotny/MSBuildSdkExtras

Edit: csproj would look like this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>netstandard1.6;portable-net45+sl5+win8</TargetFrameworks>
    <Description>YOUR DESCRIPTION</Description>
    <Company>YOUR COMPANY</Company>
    <Authors> YOUR AUTHORS </Authors>
    <Copyright>YOUR COPYRIGHT</Copyright>
    <AssemblyVersion>YOUR VERSION</AssemblyVersion>
    <FileVersion>YOUR VERSION</FileVersion>
    <PackageProjectUrl>YOUR PROJECT URL</PackageProjectUrl>
    <PackageLicenseUrl>YOUR LICENSE</PackageLicenseUrl>
    <PackageTags>YOUR TAGS</PackageTags>
    <IncludeSymbols>True</IncludeSymbols>
    <IncludeSource>True</IncludeSource>
    <GeneratePackageOnBuild>True</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
    <PackageRequireLicenseAcceptance>True</PackageRequireLicenseAcceptance>
    <Version>YOUR NUGET VERSION</Version>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="MSBuild.Sdk.Extras" Version="1.0.5" PrivateAssets="all" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <Import Project="$(MSBuildSDKExtrasTargets)" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildSDKExtrasTargets)')" />
</Project>
```

Comment: So if I use your NuGet package, what does my csproj look like then?

Comment: Here's what it'd look like:

Comment: Cool, I'm going to double check this on a couple of my projects, then mark this as the answer!

Comment: the only "gotcha" is that it is particular about the TFM's you use in portable- it must be a valid combination as TFM's aren't arbitrary. They have to map to one of the profiles as enumerated here. The order of them in the string does not matter.: https://portablelibraryprofiles.stephencleary.com/

Comment: Which I assume are the same as the Portable Class Library Full names here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/schema/target-frameworks

Comment: Yes, same list.

Answer (score 6):

**Yes**, but it's not as obvious as cross compiling `.netstandard` with `.net45` or `.net40` as the aren't easy monikers for your portable libraries predefined.

In the new sdk's [Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/blob/master/src/Tasks/Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks/build/Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets) it says:

> For cases where inference is not supported, identifier, version and
>   profile can be specified explicitly as follows:

```
   <PropertyGroup>
     <TargetFrameworks>portable-net451+win81;xyz1.0</TargetFrameworks>
   <PropertyGroup>
   <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'portable-net451+win81'">
     <TargetFrameworkIdentifier>.NETPortable</TargetFrameworkIdentifier>
     <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.6</TargetFrameworkVersion>
     <TargetFrameworkProfile>Profile44</TargetFrameworkProfile>
   </PropertyGroup>
   <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'xyz1.0'">
     <TargetFrameworkIdentifier>Xyz</TargetFrameworkVersion>
   <PropertyGroup>
```

**TargetFrameworkProfile** You get that from your old csproj/fsproj. That's the Profile identifier your portable library. You can also look it up from [Nuget Target Frameworks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/schema/target-frameworks) as well.

**TargetFrameworkIdentifier** is easy, it's `.NETPortable`

**TargetFrameworkProfile** Probably also can get from your old csproj/fsprog. But you can also check `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETPortable\` and check the `v4.0`, `v4.5`, and `v4.6` Profile directories and find your Profile. A listing of those directories is as follows:

> v4.0

```
Profile1/    Profile143/  Profile2/    Profile3/    Profile4/   Profile6/
Profile102/  Profile147/  Profile225/  Profile328/  Profile41/  Profile88/
Profile104/  Profile154/  Profile23/   Profile336/  Profile42/  Profile92/
Profile131/  Profile158/  Profile24/   Profile344/  Profile46/  Profile95/
Profile136/  Profile18/   Profile240/  Profile36/   Profile47/  Profile96/
Profile14/   Profile19/   Profile255/  Profile37/   Profile5/
```

> v4.5

```
Profile111/  Profile259/  Profile49/  Profile7/  Profile75/  Profile78/
```

> v4.6

```
Profile151/  Profile157/  Profile31/  Profile32/  Profile44/  Profile84/
```

Does the **moniker** you choose for your portable targets? Yes and no, it matters for automatically packaging for nuget, so it's best to use the value from [Nuget Target Frameworks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/schema/target-frameworks) with one caveat. I'm not sure if it's because of the newest version of nuget, but it seems to want the **TargetFrameworkVersion** added to `portable` in the moniker. So for `Profile47`, which is `v4.0`, should actually be `portable40-net45+sl5+win8`

Another item to add a compiler define which you might find useful using **DefineConstants**. You can make it anything you want, it's been historically the PROFILEXXX in caps, just add it to the Conditional Group.

```
<DefineConstants>$(DefineConstants);PROFILE47</DefineConstants>
```

The final thing to note, default **Reference** includes are not provided so you will have to add your own.

```
<ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)'=='portable40-net45+sl5+win8'">
  <Reference Include="System" />
  <Reference Include="System.Core" />
  <Reference Include="System.Windows" />
</ItemGroup>
```

**CSharp Example**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>netstandard1.6;portable40-net45+sl5+win8</TargetFrameworks>
    <Description>YOUR DESCRIPTION</Description>
    <Company>YOUR COMPANY</Company>
    <Authors> YOUR AUTHORS </Authors>
    <Copyright>YOUR COPYRIGHT</Copyright>
    <AssemblyVersion>YOUR VERSION</AssemblyVersion>
    <FileVersion>YOUR VERSION</FileVersion>
    <PackageProjectUrl>YOUR PROJECT URL</PackageProjectUrl>
    <PackageLicenseUrl>YOUR LICENSE</PackageLicenseUrl>
    <PackageTags>YOUR TAGS</PackageTags>
    <IncludeSymbols>True</IncludeSymbols>
    <IncludeSource>True</IncludeSource>
    <GeneratePackageOnBuild>True</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
    <PackageRequireLicenseAcceptance>True</PackageRequireLicenseAcceptance>
    <Version>YOUR NUGET VERSION</Version>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)'=='portable40-net45+sl5+win8'">
     <TargetFrameworkIdentifier>.NETPortable</TargetFrameworkIdentifier>
     <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
     <TargetFrameworkProfile>Profile47</TargetFrameworkProfile>
     <DefineConstants>$(DefineConstants);PROFILE47</DefineConstants>
   </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)'=='portable40-net45+sl5+win8'">
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="System.Windows" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

**F# Example**

*Caveat: F# requires beta version of Mono for Mac or Visual Studio 2017 preview 15.3 presently for this fsproj. Also a change from [examples](https://github.com/dotnet/netcorecli-fsc/blob/v1.0.3/examples/rc4/lib/lib.fsproj) includes a PackageReference to `FSharp.Compiler.Tools` and `FSharp.Core` 4.1 the last portable supported FSharp versions (which is relatively quite recent.)

```
<Project Sdk="FSharp.NET.Sdk;Microsoft.NET.Sdk" ToolsVersion="15.0">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>netstandard1.6;portable40-net45+sl5+win8</TargetFrameworks>
    <Description>YOUR DESCRIPTION</Description>
    <Company>YOUR COMPANY</Company>
    <Authors> YOUR AUTHORS </Authors>
    <Copyright>YOUR COPYRIGHT</Copyright>
    <AssemblyVersion>YOUR VERSION</AssemblyVersion>
    <FileVersion>YOUR VERSION</FileVersion>
    <PackageProjectUrl>YOUR PROJECT URL</PackageProjectUrl>
    <PackageLicenseUrl>YOUR LICENSE</PackageLicenseUrl>
    <PackageTags>YOUR TAGS</PackageTags>
    <IncludeSymbols>True</IncludeSymbols>
    <IncludeSource>True</IncludeSource>
    <GeneratePackageOnBuild>True</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
    <PackageRequireLicenseAcceptance>True</PackageRequireLicenseAcceptance>
    <Version>YOUR NUGET VERSION</Version>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)'=='portable40-net45+sl5+win8'">
     <TargetFrameworkIdentifier>.NETPortable</TargetFrameworkIdentifier>
     <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
     <TargetFrameworkProfile>Profile47</TargetFrameworkProfile>
     <DefineConstants>$(DefineConstants);PROFILE47</DefineConstants>
   </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)'=='portable40-net45+sl5+win8'">
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="System.Windows" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="FSharp.Core" Version="4.1.*" />
    <PackageReference Include="FSharp.Compiler.Tools" Version="4.1.*" PrivateAssets="All" 
    />
    <PackageReference Include="FSharp.NET.Sdk" Version="1.0.*" PrivateAssets="All" 
    />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="YourModule1.fs" />
    <Compile Include="YourModule2.fs" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```